# Buffer input while prompt is loading in zsh

Tags: zsh

After running a command in `zsh`, especially after <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, there is a pause before my prompt is displayed again. In bash, when this happens, anything typed before the prompt reappears
is still counted as input, even if it displays before the new prompt or is erased by it. This means I can type <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> + `ls` + <kbd>enter</kbd> as fast as I can, and `ls` will still run. On `zsh`, I
often just end up with `s`, the `l` being entered too quickly. Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> then submits only `s`.

I've tried googling "zsh buffer input while prompt loading" and a few variants, but found nothing.

I have tried disabling my prompt plugin, and all other plugins, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this myself. There were functions in my `zshrc` swallowing input.

Comment: How about accepting your own answer, so this question doesn't remain open?